# Compile time type check

Tags: c#, generics, collections, parameters

imagine a generic class B

```
public class B<T> : IB
{
   public void Foo(object parameter)
   {
      var param = (T)parameter;
      //...
   }
}
```

And a class A, which get's a collection of Bs passed through it's constructor. Notice im using the interface `IB` as type there.

```
public class A
{
   public A(IEnumerable<IB> collectionOfBs) {}

}
```

Sometime later, I want to execute some Method on class A, let's say foo, which will take a collection of objects of type `T`, where `T` is the generic type of the instance of `B` passed in the constructor. so these types have to match.

```
public void foo(IEnumerable<object> param)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < collectionOfBs.Count(); i++)
   {
     collectionOfBs.ElementAt(i).Foo(param.ElementAt(i));
   }
}
```

Right now im passing an `IEnumerable<object>` and cast to type `T` inside of foo, that will work but I'm wondering if I could have this type check at compile time instead?

Any Ideas if thats possible or not?
Thanks

Comment: As far as A knows from what you have written, the concrete class of IB might not have such a <T> to work with at all. You could make your `IB` interface generic as well.

Comment: `IB` knows nothing about type `T`. Only class `B` knows what `T` is. One option I can think of is put the method `foo` in the class `B<T>` instead

Comment: Imagine having `var b1 = new B<string>(); var b2 = new B<int>();` and then you create an instance of `A` like this `var a = new A(new IB[] { b1, b2 });`. What would be _"the generic type of the instance of B passed in the constructor"_ in this case? Not to mention the case where `a = new A(new IB[] { b1, b2, c });` and `c` is an object of type `C` which _also_ implements `IB`.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed the enuerable would have to look like {5, "bar" }. Does this answer your question?

Comment: @SimplyGed I don't think this is an option, `foo` iterates over all instances of `IB` and passes the parameter to them.

Comment: Can you provide your actual code for `public void foo(IEnumerable<object> param)`, please?

Comment: @OlivierRogier sorry but i think all information needed is given, I do not share this point. It might be a bit abstract, but that should be no problem, as we all work with such structures every day

Comment: @OlivierRogier The cast has to happen in `B.Foo()` as only `B` knows `T`

Comment: sounds like an https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem to me

Answer (score 0):

You can try this using a generic method for the type of the provided parameter.

It does not ensure that TParam and T are same, since you have a non generic interface, but is it the best you can do, as I know, according to a first study of your problem...

Because there is no diamond operator in C# to allow true generic polymorphism on open types.

```
    public interface IB
    {
      void Foo<TParam>(TParam parameter);
    }

    public class B<T> : IB
    {
      public void Foo<TParam>(TParam parameter)
      {
        var param = parameter;
        Console.WriteLine("param type: " + param.GetType().Name);
      }
    }

    public class A
    {
      private IEnumerable<IB> CollectionOfBs;

      public A(IEnumerable<IB> collectionOfBs)
      {
        CollectionOfBs = collectionOfBs;
      }

      public void Foo(IEnumerable<object> param)
      {
        if ( param.Count() < CollectionOfBs.Count() )
          throw new ArgumentException();
        for ( int i = 0; i < CollectionOfBs.Count(); i++ )
          CollectionOfBs.ElementAt(i).Foo(param.ElementAt(i));
      }
    }
```

*Test method*

```
    static void Test()
    {
      var listInstances = new List<IB> { new B<int>(), new B<double>(), new B<string>() };

      var container = new A(listInstances);

      var listParams = new List<object> { 2, 4.3, "test" };

      container.Foo(listParams);
    }
```

*Output*

```
param type: Int32
param type: Double
param type: String
```

*Considerations*

The problem here is that any bad matching parameter type can be passed.

For example with the Test(), you can have a double instead of the first integer and it works: you get a Double on your Int32 instance...

```
param type: Double
param type: Double
param type: String
```

Having the diamond operator `<>` you will be able to use a generic interface and parse on a closed constructed types list... and your design will have a better smell:

```
public interface IB<T>
{
  void Foo(T parameter);
}

public class B<T> : IB<T>
{
  public void Foo(T parameter)

  {
    var param = parameter;
    Console.WriteLine("param type: " + param.GetType().Name);
  }
}

public class A
{
  private IEnumerable<IB<>> CollectionOfBs;

  public A(IEnumerable<IB<>> collectionOfBs)
  {
    CollectionOfBs = collectionOfBs;
  }

  public void Foo(IEnumerable<object> param)
  {
    if ( param.Count() < CollectionOfBs.Count() )
      throw new ArgumentException();
    for ( int i = 0; i < CollectionOfBs.Count(); i++ )
    {
      CollectionOfBs.ElementAt(i).Foo(param.ElementAt(i));
    }
  }
}
```

Hence with that, any bad matching type of parameter will raise an exception at runtime.

Comment: But here the instance of A would determine the type `T` and so all instances of `B` would have to have the same generic type `T` also? (See Ahmeds comment and my answer)

Comment: Looks promising, I will check later, don't have time right now ;)

Answer (score -1):

When you want consistent generic type checking, you need to apply generics consistently. Currently, you are using a half-way approach: `B<T>` is generic, but `IB` is not. Then you have a non-generic class `A`, which couples to the non-generic interface `IB`, but you want compile-time type checking of `T`, which both, `A` and `IB` know nothing about (only to internally cast it to `T`). That's a bit of a problem.

From the usage of your classes/interface it seems obvious that you don't expect mixed `IB` implementations in `A`, so what you can do is to consistently apply the generic type parameter `T` on all types:

```
public class B<T> : IB<T>
{
   public void Foo(T parameter)
   {
      var param = parameter;
      //...
   }
}

public class A<T>
{
    public A(IEnumerable<IB<T>> collectionOfBs) {}

    public void foo(IEnumerable<T> param)
    {
       collectionOfBs.Zip(param, (b, t) => { b.Foo(t); return 0 });
    }
}
```

Note that I replaced your approach with `for` and `ElementAt` by `Enumerable.Zip`.